# Create-react-app absolute imports don't work with yarn v2 workspaces + typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2

I'm using yarn v2 workspaces, and one of my workspaces is a frontend built with `create-react-app` / `react-scripts`. I want to enable absolute imports within the frontend app, so I can do things like `import Button from 'components/Button'` instead of `import Button from '../../../components/Button'`. Note that my issue is *not* to do with cross-workspace imports.

I've followed [the instructions in the CRA docs for enabling absolute imports](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports), and everything is working except for `tsc`:

- ✅ The app runs
- ✅ The app builds
- ✅ The tests pass
- ❌ `yarn tsc --noEmit` gives an error like this on any absolute import:

  ```
  error TS2307: Cannot find module 'components/Button' or its corresponding type declarations.
  ```

This also results in red squigglies under the import statement in my editor (vscode).

My project structure is like this:

```
package.json
tsconfig.json
workspaces/
  - backend
  - frontend
    - package.json
    - tsconfig.json
    - src/
      - components/Button.tsx
      - pages/PageWithAButton.tsx
```

Here's the root `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  }
}
```

And the frontend `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "../shared" }]
}
```

I invoke tsc using this command from the root directory:

```
yarn tsc --noEmit --jsx preserve
```

How can I make tsc resolve the absolute import?

Answer (score 3):

According to Yarn 2+ documentation the link protocol is recommended over aliases and (TypeScript) path mapping:
https://yarnpkg.com/features/protocols#why-is-the-link-protocol-recommended-over-aliases-for-path-mapping

It is better to remove `paths` from your `tsconfig.json` and instead add to `package.json`:

```json
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "components": "link:./src/components"
}
```

After that you should run

```
yarn
```

for changes to `package.json` to take effect

Answer (score 0):

In `compilerOptions` of `tsconfig.json` , you add `path` like this:

```
"paths": {
  "components/*": ["src/components/*"]
}
```

Comment: That didn't fix it. According to the tsconfig docs, `paths` should be relative to the `baseUrl`. So I tried just setting `"components/*": ["components/*"]` and that didn't help either :(